# why am i still getting an error of NumberFormatException?

Tags: java, numberformatexception

well I'm pretty sure i took care of the error but whenever i try testing a string in the place of an integer it keeps sending an error although i specified to handle it.

i made the textField only accept integers, however i want it to display that if the string is entered it will send a JOptionPane saying only numbers are allowed.

here's my whole code :

```
    public void giveItem() {
    try {
        String itemId = textField1.getText();
        String itemAmount = textField2.getText();

    if (isTargetEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null, "Please enter a player to continue!", "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE
        );
    } else if (itemId.isEmpty() || itemAmount.isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null,"Please fill the required fields!", "Error",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE
        );
    } else {

        String player = getTargetName();
        Player target = World.getPlayerByDisplayName(player);
        if (target != null) {

            int id = Integer.parseInt(itemId);
            int amount = Integer.parseInt(itemAmount);

            if (Double.isNaN(id) || Double.isNaN(amount)){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                        null, "You can only enter numbers!", "Error!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE
                );

        } else if (amount <= target.getInventory().getFreeSlots()) {

            target.getInventory().addItem(id, amount);
            target.getPackets().sendGameMessage(
                "You have received " + (amount > 1 ? " Items!" : "an Item!")
        );
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null, Utils.formatPlayerNameForDisplay(target.getUsername()) + " has received the " +
                (amount > 1 ? "Items successfully in his/her inventory." : "Item successfully in his/her inventory.")
        );
        logAction(SPSutil.getTime() + Utils.formatPlayerNameForDisplay(target.getUsername())
                + " has received the item : "  + id + ". Amount : " + amount + " in his/her inventory."
        );
        } else {
            target.getBank().addItem(id, amount, true);
            target.getPackets().sendGameMessage(
                    "You have received " + (amount > 1 ? "Items in your bank!" : "an Item in your bank!")
            );
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    null, Utils.formatPlayerNameForDisplay(target.getUsername()) + " has received the " +
                    (amount > 1 ? "Items successfully in his/her bank." : "Item successfully in his/her bank.")
            );
            logAction(SPSutil.getTime() + Utils.formatPlayerNameForDisplay(target.getUsername())
                    + " has received the item : "  + id + ". Amount : " + amount + " in his/her bank."
            );
        }
    } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    null , "Player does not exist!", "Error" , JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE
            );
        }
 }
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: First check if its Number(`instanceof`), then parse it to your new Type.

Comment: Where are you catching `NumberFormatException`?

Comment: @Boolena at which line the numberformatexception is happening.

Answer (score 4):

[`Double.isNaN()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#isNaN--) will *not* check whether a number is valid after a parse. This method's argument is a `double` (your `id` is therefore automatically promoted) and it only checks whether this `double` is [`Double.NaN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NaN). Which no `int` can ever be, even promoted.

What you must do is:

```
try {
    int id = Integer.parseInt(itemId);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // not an integer
}
```

Comment: +1 an `int` cannot be NaN. BTW `Double.isNaN(Float.NaN)` is also true.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you get it when invoke method `Integer.parseInt(itemAmount);`. You should wrap it using `try...catch` statement and handle this case properly.